# Variables initialization on struct definition Debug vs Release mode

Tags: c++, windows

I am working on some DLLs to be loaded on Windows. At Debug Mode everything works fine. At Release mode is working too, but I already found some issues that I had to fix in cases of class initialization.

I know it is a simple and basic issue, but as I did already find some issues with it I am not thrusting 100 % the option A on Release mode.

Is is it really so that some kind of optimization may bypass the variables initialization like A on Release mode, so better do always like B, or probably did something else happend wrong at the cases I found? (not this one, hard to track now)

I am working with MSVC++ 14.16 _MSC_VER == 1916 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9)

A)

```
struct slista_meta
{
    slista_meta(IBlock * bk);
    bool rodando = false, parar = false;
}
```

B)

```
slista_meta::slista_meta(IBlock * bk)
{
     rodando = parar = false;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to give some description of the "some issues" you found were.  Even better, give a compilable example so that people can see the issues for themselves, and experiment with them on their own machine.

Comment: The only way to know if an issue is simple and basic is to know what the issue is. Since you know it is simple and basic... *(Have more confidence that your question is valid, and less confidence that your conclusions are correct. Describe what you've seen. Describe what you've tried. Give people a chance to check your conclusions by providing a [mcve].)*

Comment: Debug build tends to initialize uninitialized variables to 0. "Hiding" the UB of reading non-initialized variables. Check your initialization.

Comment: I personally prefer A style, then initializer list: `slista_meta::slista_meta(IBlock * bk) : rodando(false), parar (false) {}`.